# String to int conversion

Tags: java, arrays, string, int

Long story short, the snippets below is about converting the texted month to numbered month (ex, Jan -> 1). There's no error but in the end I keep getting 0 as the result of m. Where's the problem?

```
//date1s[] is the result of splitting date1 by spaces (date1 = 1 Jan 2012)
m = convertMonth(date1s[1]); //date1s[1] contains the Month; date1s[0] the date and date1s[2] the year

public int convertMonth(String monw) {
        int x = 0;
        if (monw == "Jan") {
            x = 1;
        }
        else if (monw == "Feb") {
            x = 2;
        } 
        else if (monw == "Mar") {
            x = 3;
        } 
        else if (monw == "Apr") {
            x = 4;
        } 
        else if (monw == "May") {
            x = 5;
        } 
        else if (monw == "Jun") {
            x = 6;
        } 
        else if (monw == "Jul") {
            x = 7;
        } 
        else if (monw == "Aug") {
            x = 8;
        } 
        else if (monw == "Sep") {
            x = 9;
        } 
        else if (monw == "Oct") {
            x = 10;
        } 
        else if (monw == "Nov") {
            x = 11;
        } 
        else if (monw == "Dec") {
            x = 12;
        }
        return x;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `.equals()` method of String.

`if (monw.equals("Jan"))`

When you use `==` operator, it compares the memory locations of the two objects and returns `false`. In other words, it only returns `true` if the same object is on both sides of equation. So you should use the `.equals()` method instead, which returns `true` if two different objects have the same value.

**EDIT:**
I just checked, @LazyCubicleMonkey is right. The `==` operator checks if locations in memory are the same. I created a class, overrided the `hashCode()` method, created two objects and printed `obj1==obj2`. It prints `false`.

Comment: It does not compare hashcodes. It compares locations in memory. (You were probably thinking of the default implementation of hashCode, System.identityHashCode(Object x)).

Answer (score 4):

Instead of doing

```
if (monw == "Jan") {
            x = 1;
        }
```

Use,

```
if (monw.equals("Jan")) {
            x = 1;
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

You're using `==` rather than `equals()` for String comparison.

Comment: how can you make sure that monw was not created using new String("some Value")? as in that case it would fail

Comment: The problem in the question was that `equals()` should be used rather than `==`. While `==` can work in rare cases (where it really is the same String object), `equals()` will work all the time. Ideally it should be called as `monw.equals("Jan")`, so that subclasses of String work too.

Comment: Good point... assuming your point is that `String` is a final class.   You can however create classes implementing `Comparable<String>`, which is the reason you'd use `monw.equals("Jan")` instead of `"Jan".equals(monw)`. (In that case you'd want to use the `monw` implementation of `equals()`).

Answer (score 3):

Your problem of string comparision is very well explained by others so I will not rewrite that. Other than that...

In your case, *if your month names are contant*,  it will be *better* to use a `Map<String,Integer>` of month names and value or `Enum` having month names. It will omit your long `if...else..if...else` conditions.

---

Enum example:

```
public enum Month {
    Jan,
    Feb,
    Mar,
    Apr,
    // ...
    Dec
}    
public int toMonthInt(String input) {
    return Month.valueOf(input).ordinal() + 1; // +1 because you want Month value to start with 1.
}
```

---

Map example:

```
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    map.put("Jan", 1);
    map.put("Feb", 2);
    map.put("Mar", 3);
    map.put("Apr", 4);
    // ...
    map.put("Dec", 12);
    System.out.println(map.get("Jan"));
```

Comment: Yeah but I'm creating this for a BlackBerry Application so enum and map doesn't work (tried just now) but thanks anyway :D

Comment: @AnthonyPangestu, I'm pretty sure `Map` is present, it's called HashTable.

Comment: Btw the code runs well in the simulator but it gives "Uncaught expression: Jan". Since "Jan" is a string in the code, I think the error is located there. I think I should try to use Map like u suggested but how to use it?

Comment: @AnthonyPangestu : I have no experience in BB, but in java I have shown the way to do it in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

In Java7, you can use the `switch` statement, instead of `if-else`. It supports String too.

Comment: @AnthonyPangestu: You should mention BlackBerry in your post, then, and use the BlackBerry flag.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ("Jan".equals (monw))
{  
     x = 1;
}
```

Comment: It's generally helpful to include the reason why the corrected code works.

Answer (score 0):

Another lean approach would be, to store the Names in a List:

```
List <String> as = Arrays.asList ("Jan", "Feb", "Mar");
System.out.println (as.indexOf ("Feb")); 
System.out.println (as.indexOf ("Fex"));
```

The first returns 1, the second -1. For you, you would add +1 to the 0-based index, and check for it not being 0 in the end or -1 in the beginning.

I'm not sure whether this works on Blackberry.